# How to use async/await to retrieve value from AsyncStorage in react native by using function

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have created prefsManager.js - Use for storing and retrieve data from AsyncStorage but I have faced a problem like when print log it return always undefined because of it is Async but I want to print the actual value in a log by the call of the function.

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import prefskey from '../utils/constants/prefskeys';

const setValue = async (key, value) => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
}

const getValue = async (key) => {
    let value = '';
    try {
        value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key) || 'none';
    } catch (error) {
        // Error retrieving data 
        console.log(error.message);
    }
    return value;
};

const prefsmanager = {
    setValue,
    getValue
}
export default prefsmanager;
```

I have used this in my Home.js when button press I'm calling this method.

```
_handlePress() {

        await prefsManager.setValue(prefskey.username, this.state.username)

        console.log("username =>>", await prefsManager.getValue(prefskey.username)); 

     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use async keyword on your function like this.

```
    import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import prefskey from '../utils/constants/prefskeys';

const prefsnamager = {

    setValue: function (key, value) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value)
    },

    getValue: async (key) => {
        let value = '';
        try {
            value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key) || 'none';
        } catch (error) {
            // Error retrieving data
            console.log(error.message);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
export default prefsnamager;
```

calling function

```
_handlePress = () => {
        prefsManager.setValue(prefskey.username, this.state.username)

        console.log("username =>>" , prefsManager.getValue(prefskey.username));

     }
```

Comment: I don't want to write in every screen i just call function from prefsmanager class and return value which i have passed key as argument.

Comment: You can use this function in prefsmanager class just add the argument key in the function and call it anywhere. I have updated my previous answer Please take a look

Comment: It gives me syntex error , there is no function keyword.

Comment: I have tried but it prints like
'username =>>', { _40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null } in log.

Comment: You don't need the "function" keyword while using fat arrow function in getValue function and you need to pass an argument "key" in getValue function like

`getValue = async(key) =>`

and you need to change and update this line to this

`value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key) || 'none';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186756/discussion-between-vishal-patoliya--and-rishabh-rawat).

Answer (score 2):

1. Set value in storage

```js
AsyncStorage.setItem('data','Read Data')
```

2. Get value from storage

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props)       

    this.state = {};
    let self=this;

    //this function is called everytime , when you visit this screen.
    this.__didFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus',payload => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('data').then((value)=>{
            if(value==null){
                self.setState({count:'no data found'})
            }
            else{
                self.setState({count:value})
            }
        })
    });       
}
```

Comment: I want this in separate file and i want to call from there rather than define in every screen.

Comment: I have created prefsnamager.js and in this file i have define Getter and Setter of AsyncStorage methods and i want to call function from there by importing   prefsnamager.js into my home.js and call function from prefsnamager.js for setting and getting value from preference.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is like `localStorage` in the web but with a little difference. in getting the item it acts asynchronously. pay attention to below:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('key', value);
```

But in getting it is like below:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('key')
  .then( value => console.log(value) );
```

Comment: Can we take callback from then and put into our screen ?

Comment: Dear @VishalPatoliyaツ, what does it mean _take callback_? inside `then` you can pass a callback function and do anything you want. and inside `catch` you can pass fallback function and then anything you want.